# C# EF LINQ не может найти русские символы, как исправить?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq2sql, charset

Есть бд на MicrosoftSqlServer. В ней есть таблица Metro и атрибуты Name varchar (100). Так же у атрибута стоит кодировка cyrillic_general_ci_as. В значении бдд на русском языке. Например "Автово". Но код возвращает null. `var metro = await _context.Metro.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Name == "Автово");` Знаю, что в Tsql надо добавить N перед строкой и все найдется. Как это сделать в Entity Framework? Версия Entity Framework 3.1.22.

Попытка подключения подключения кодировки и получение ошибки "Ключевое слово не поддерживается: 'charset'." Строка подключения выглядит так `Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX` С добавлением кодировки так Строка подключения выглядит так `Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;CharSet=utf8`

Comment: Заменить `varchar` на `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 1):

Помогло заменить `varchar` на `nvarchar`.